# how to configure vue-router in nuxt3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, nuxt3, vuetifyjs3

trying to migrate from nuxt2 to nuxt3, and in my old project i have html code like this

```
    <v-btn  to="/create" depressed class="btn_text" color="grey darken-4">
      Create Order
    </v-btn>
```

in nuxt3 this type routing to="" not working. it gives me this error

```
500(error)

RouterLink.useLink is not a function
at Object.setup [as _setup] (./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VBtn/VBtn.mjs:148:41)
```

i have tried to manually connect package vue-router by writting plugin in nuxt3

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {

  const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: []
  })
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(router)
})
```

it gives me this error

```
window is not defined

at Proxy.createWebHistory (./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.cjs.js:597:31)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt 3 automatically builds your routes from the contents of your project's "pages" subdirectory.  References to pages inside your site then use the NuxtLink component, which can be embedded in button or list item content, like this:

```
<v-btn><NuxtLink to="/create">Create Order</NuxtLink></v-btn>
```

Here's [the official guide](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/routing).

Comment: i know i wanted to avoid extra elements by just using :to in v-btn like in nuxt2